# Can't get Javascript to fire from c# codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have read many posts here and many other sites and so I've gathered a few versions of HOW to do this. My problem is that I can't get it to do anything.

Here's the Javascript, just an alert for testing:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ICDcheck() {
                alert('Patient has an ineligible diagnosis code!');
        }
    </script>
```

I tested this manually by adding the function to an OnClientClick of a button and it worked fine.

Here is what I've tried in the codebehind:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "uniqueKey", "ICDcheck()", true);
```

and...

```
    string jsMethodName = "ICDcheck()";
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(string), "uniqueKey", jsMethodName, true);
```

and...

```
    lblJavaScript.Text = "<script type='text/javascript'>ICDcheck();</script>";
```

This last one references a label I have sitting at the top of my asp : Content just below a  script and the asp : ScriptManager block.

I've placed these bits in the button_click, the page_load, the sqldatasource_selecting, the formview_PageIndexChanging and always the same, nothing.

As always, thanks for your patience and help. My ignorance will likely be exposed as the problem, but I'm learning.

Comment: Try Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    GetType(), 
    "MyKey", 
    "ICDcheck();", 
    true); Also install firebug and check if there are any script errors.

Comment: Check using IsClientScriptBlockRegistered method if script with "uniqueKey" is alredy registered or not . Please see more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa5tktc9.aspx

Comment: YES! Sam, that worked. Good grief I would love to know why there are so many ways to accomplish the same thing and why some of them work for some people and not for others. Or are these others meant to be used in specific cases which I am not fully aware? Either way, thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: @R_Scott well for me I had same issue scriptmanager was not running. the reason behind it was that my page had usercontrols and as I remember it wasn't firing - I will put it as answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Page.ClientScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clientscript.aspx) :

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript( GetType(), "MyKey", "ICDcheck();", true);
```

Also install [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and check if there are any script errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. On your page, have a button:

```
<asp:Button ID="RunJsButton" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Then, in the code-behind, inject the script into the response and add the wireup to the button:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string scriptToRun = @"function ICDcheck() { alert('Patient has an ineligible diagnosis code!');}";

        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "", scriptToRun, true);
        RunJsButton.OnClientClick = "return ICDcheck();";
    }
```

If that is the kind of thing you are after, you can refactor it a bit to implement best practice.

Comment: I'll test this as well in hopes of understanding these things better. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @R_Scott If you want to get really fancy, you can create a class like the one in these two posts [first](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Feb/12/Embedding-ASPNET-Server-Variables-in-Client-JavaScript) and [second](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Feb/21/Embedding-ASPNET-Server-Variables-in-Client-JavaScript-Part-2) . I used to use something like that when I used to write Web-forms apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<button ID="your_btn" onclick="javascript:your_function(); return false;"><asp:literal ID="your_literal" runat="server" /></button>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function your_function() {
            alert('Patient has an ineligible diagnosis code!');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
string jsToRun = "<script language=javascript>ICDcheck();</script>";

Type csType = this.GetType();

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Key", jsToRun);
```